# Failed to deploy Nightmarejs app to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, electron, nightmare

*EDIT - 1/6/2020*

My solution finally is moving to puppeteer.js, deployed to Heroku with zero problems, and took me 15 min the change the code since the API is similar. so if anyone gets those issues with nightmare.js I recommend you take a look at puppeteer.js good luck!

*--*

After a long struggle, I came here eventually seeking for any clue for a solution

I am trying to deploy nightmarejs app to heroku (which works perfectly on my mac).
I followed all the guides that I could found on the internet, including:

[oscarmorrison](https://github.com/oscarmorrison/nightmare-heroku)

[johann.pardanaud](https://medium.com/@johann.pardanaud/running-electron-on-heroku-db3866a690a3)

[kireerik](https://github.com/kireerik/nightmare-heroku-example#set-up-heroku-app)

I also tried [this](https://www.techighness.com/post/how-to-run-nightmare-js-remote-linux-server/)

I kept getting errors that some packages missing so I adjusted the Aptfile followed by what I found online.

eventually the error I receive now is - `electron:stderr /app/node_modules/electron/dist/electron: symbol lookup error: /app/node_modules/electron/dist/electron: undefined symbol: udata_setCommonData_59
nightmare electron child process exited with code 127: command not found - you may not have electron installed correctly`

my buildpacks are:

1. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt
2. https://github.com/captain401/heroku-buildpack-xvfb.git
3. https://github.com/ubuntugod/heroku-electron-buildpack.git
4. heroku/nodejs

using heroku-18 as the stack.

My Aptfile:

```
xvfb
x11-xkb-utils
xfonts-100dpi
xfonts-75dpi
xfonts-scalable
xfonts-cyrillic
libxfont1
libnotify4
libxss1
libgconf-2-4
libgtkextra-dev
libgconf2-dev
libnss3
libasound2
libxtst-dev
libxinerama1
libcairo-gobject2
x11-apps
clang
libdbus-1-dev
libgtk2.0-dev
libnotify-dev
libgnome-keyring-dev
libasound2-dev
libcap-dev
libcups2-dev
libnss3-dev
gcc-multilib
g++-multilib
```

there are probably some packages that don't really necessary in the Aptfile but after so many tries I'm totally confuse

My Procfile:

```
web: DEBUG=*  xvfb-run --auto-servernum --server-args="-screen 0 1280x1028x24 -ac +extension GLX +render" node --harmony ./build/app.js
```

nightmare version - 3.0.2

nodejs version - 12.13.0

npm version - 6.12.0

let me know if there is anything else that need to be share here.

if someone can provide any information I'll be grateful!

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get install -y \
  xvfb \
  x11-xkb-utils \
  xfonts-100dpi \
  xfonts-75dpi \
  xfonts-scalable \
  xfonts-cyrillic \
  x11-apps \
  clang \
  libdbus-1-dev \
  libgtk2.0-dev \
  libnotify-dev \
  libgnome-keyring-dev \
  libgconf2-dev \
  libasound2-dev \
  libcap-dev \
  libcups2-dev \
  libxtst-dev \
  libxss1 \
  libnss3-dev \
  gcc-multilib \
  g++-multilib
```

https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/224#issuecomment-365938300

Seems `xvfb` package is missing on your apt file

Comment: My mistake with the copy and paste here. this package is included in the Aptfile but thanks!!